# How to access on HP iLO 2's remote console from macOS

Tags: remote-desktop, hp-proliant, remote-access, ilo

I have an old HP Proliant DL380 G5 which comes with iLO (Integrated Lights Out) version 2 for remote control of the server.

This includes features such as power on/off and remote console access accessible through a browser. The first works fine while the latter (remote console) relies on technologies that are ancient in the digital wold; Either IE7 + ActiveX, or any browser capable of running Java Applets.

Java Applets were afaik removed from all browser this year except IE.

Does anyone how to work around this and connect to the remote console from a computer running macOS?

Comment: Start by installing Java. See https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml

Comment: I already have Java installed, however none of the browsers I have tried (Safari, Firefox, Chrome) are capable of running Java Applets any longer. These browsers have had Java Applet support removed in the last year or so.

Comment: https://dev.karakun.com/webstart/

Answer (score 2):

Ouch.

These are 9-year-old servers, so you will probably need an 9-year-old operating system to get into the iLO.

Your best bet is probably to install a Windows Visa/Windows 7 virtual machine on your Mac (using Parallels or VMWare Fusion), install a similarly old version of Java and use the ancient version of Internet Explorer it comes with to access the iLO.

I've had to do this before for a SuperMicro BMC. It sucks but it's pretty much the only way to do it now.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to run on a Linux machine before by [downloading `jar` archive from iLO.](https://kudzia.eu/b/2011/09/ilo/).

You may be able to get `jar` archive from iLO:

http://your.iLO/M2.JAR

and may be run with `java` command:

`java -jar M2.JAR`

But, modern browsers will prevent you from downloading `jar` archive as the malicious file.

Comment: File is name rc150p08.jar, so http://your.iLO/rc150p08.jar . Pasted that url into Firefox, no problem downloading. Running it with `java -jar` didn't work because the manifest file doesn't specify a main class, makes sense since it's an applet. I'll try to write a small cmd line Java application that starts it up.

Answer (score 1):

HPE seems to be a little bit ignorant of Apple (OS X) users here. But, if you happen to have any iOS device (iPad / iPhone), the iOS app "iLO" might be a workaround for you. For me, it works very well on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by having a VM with old software that is still compatible. Fedora 25 has a version of Firefox that stil supports NPAPI plugins (<=51). All that is needed out of the box is `dnf install icedtea-web`. This enables Java applets.